# UDP PACKET TRANSFERRING

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am using a UDP child process and i want to send the output of the command given by the father process to the client (client is connected to father with TCP). What i've done is shown below but it's not working as i want. I need to send the output as messages of 512 bytes maximum (i.e if the message is 600 bytes then it should send 512 + 88 bytes). The client should also exit when he gets the messages but it won't exit in my case. I tried to use dup2 as i've seen through examples but it doesn't work on UDP since no connection is established

```
//child process
FILE *fp;
fp = popen(s, "r"); //s = "ls"
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
    sendto(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1,  MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 
}

pclose(fp);       
n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, 512, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, &len); 
printf("Client : %s\n", buffer); 

close(sockfd); 

//client process
int len; 

len = sizeof(cliaddr); 

while(recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,  MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len)){ 
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
sendto(sockfd, (const char *)hello, strlen(hello), MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, len); 
printf("Hello message sent.\n"); 

return 0;
```

Comment: *"it's not working as i want"*  How exactly?  What behavior are your seeing compared to what you expect?  Also, try removing the `MSG_WAITALL` and `MSG_CONFIRM` flags.

Comment: Like i need to know a way when the client receives the whole message. The ls command is executed properly, sent to the client side and nothing more happens. I have to kill the client process and it won't execute the two commands after the while loop

Comment: With UDP there's no such thing as getting a partial message.  You either get the whole packet or nothing.  The `MSG_WAITALL` flag is probably preventing that, as it's means for TCP.

Comment: I set all the flags equal to 0 and nothing changed. Client gets the ls output properly but nothing happens then. He won't execute sendto printf and terminate after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop in the client will never exit.

By default a call to `recvfrom` is blocking.  That means it will wait until it received data, so if no data is coming it just sits there.  Unlike TCP there's no connection that can be closed so `recvfrom` won't return 0.

You need to have some way for the server to tell the client that it's done sending data so that the client knows when to respond, perhaps a 1 byte message with the byte set to 0.

Comment: that was the issue. Thank you for your time!